# need JQM event that fires after page reload

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there an event that will fire after a same page tranisition (refresh of the page?) I've tried `$(document).bind('pageinit'), pageshow, etc...`

```
    $.mobile.changePage("#myPage", { allowSamePageTransition : true, reloadPage: true } );
```

Comment: Maybe try to check the Page Load Events. Here is the link listing all the events: [http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)